# Phonegap iFrame Blank iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, iframe

I'm using phonegap 2.6 on iOS in the config.xml I have the following:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

But when I use an iframe say to display google.com for testing it just displays an empty iframe.

```
<iframe width="300px" height="400px" frameborder="1" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

Any ideas I am using iPhone 5, iOS 6.1.3, Phonegap 2.6 and Jquery Mobile?

Comment: I can get the iframe to display a local page just not external.

Comment: Had the same problem, see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458909/how-do-i-embed-iframe-in-phonegap-app/17462248#17462248

Answer (score 0):

Write into your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*.website.com" />
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Use other URL, because google doesn't open in iFrame.