# Phonegap white screen when redirecting to a website

Tags: phonegap-build

I am trying to make an app that simply redirects users to my website the minute it starts.

The app does the redirection wonderfully on PC, the PhoneGap app has my icon displaying and building using PhoneGap shows no error; However when starting the app from a phone it only shows a white screen.

I tried to Phonegap my website instead of externally calling it and it worked perfectly. I'd appreciate your valuable comments on how to call my website externally.

I have 3 files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script scr="phonegap.js"> </script>
<script src="myPhoneApp.js"> </script>
</head>
<body onload="myPhoneApp();">
</body>
</html>
```

**myPhoneApp.js**

```
function myPhoneApp()
{
window.location="http://www.myqourse.com";
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   =   "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap   =   "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id          =   "com.########.########" --->personal info
versionCode =   "1"
version     =   "1.0.0">
<name>######</name> --->personal info
<description> MyQourse Mobile App </description>
<author href="http://www.############.com" email="###########@hotmail.com" >######### </author> --->personal info
<platform name="ios"/>
<platform name="android"/>
<platform name="winphone"/>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.1.0"/>
<!--General preferences-->
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="disallowoverscroll" value="true"/>
<!--access, permissions and icons-->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<!--ios preferences-->
<preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0"/>
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="false"/>
<preference name="StatusBarOverlayWebView" value="false"/>
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default"/>
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default"/>
<!--android preferences-->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21"/>
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
<!--simple icon-->
<icon src="icon.png" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Remember that if you tell the browser window, where Phonegap is running, to relocate, you are navigating away from your phonegapp app.
Maybe its better for you to add a full-size iframe and let it load the page you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you just want people to see your website, and have that as a native app you should just make a big iframe pointed towards your website instead of redirecting the main container.

Here is another question asking to [embed an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458909/how-do-i-embed-iframe-in-phonegap-app) in an PhoneGap App.

Comment: So I could understand from what you say that it is not possible to view the external website from within the app?