# Cordova - how to redirect to another page. Always open in new external browser

Tags: android, cordova, web, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

In my index.html file I have **window.location='http:....'**, and I am able to release the application to android.

When running the application on an android phone, i am **asked what browser** I should open it with, chrome or browser.

Obviously, my intention is to run the external application as a phonegap application.

**Is this not posbbile?**

This guide also suggests this to be possible:

http://antonylees.blogspot.se/2013/02/launch-website-as-mobile-app-using.html

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
    -->
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            window.location = "http://81.224.20.10:8080";
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="mycmpany.tv" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>mycmpany.tv</name>
    <description>
        Watch Tv from all over the world, anywhere, everywhere.
    </description>
    <author email="mo@mycmpany.com" href="http://mycmpany.tv">
        mycmpany.tv team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />

    <access origin="http://83.254.80.10:8080" subdomains="true"/>

    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />   

    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18"/>
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>

        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

**What am I missing?**

Note, I tried with the cordova.InAppBrowser but unfortunately you'd get the adress bar and all there, and still not a great solution.

Comment: You could also use an iframe, like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458909/how-do-i-embed-iframe-in-phonegap-app), but the X-Frame-Options of a website must not be defined with a value like SAMEORIGIN or DENY otherwise the frame stays blank in your app.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work, however, websockets is not working, and localstorage gets cleared when application is closed down. annoying.

Comment: Really? With me http://www.google.com stayed black. Nevertheless this might be another question.

Comment: I think it has to do with google.com defining that you can't not cross origin it, so it's not available through an iframe.

Comment: @Blauharley localstorage in parent window works fine, but on the iframe it is always cleared on application restart. And websockets doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: I did not know that you want me to answer that. Sorry, as you already said cross-side-script is not allowed with that page. If was your page then you could also use php GET params to communicate in some way with that page, but I can not help you to get localstorage/websockets to work here :(

Comment: Uh... the IP address you whitelisted is not the one you're trying to open...

Comment: I notice that you have iOS settings in your config.xml. If you're planning on launching in the Apple store, my understanding of Apple's Review Guidelines and process is that an app that is simply a redirect to a web site (or rehash of one locally on the device) will likely be rejected.